# Getting today, yesterday and next days' date and switch between those

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

I am working on a date picker, the date picker is supposed to have three parts

```
PREV DAY            TODAY             NEXT DAY
```

`TODAY` initially shows today's date, but if the user clicks on next day it will be changed to the date of the next day.

For e.g

```
< 25th Jan 2018               26th Jan 2018           27th Jan 2018 >
```

When they click on "27th Jan 2018" the three parts are supposed to change in this manner

```
< 26th Jan 2018               27th Jan 2018           28th Jan 2018 >
```

I am using Moment JS and have done this so far:

```
<div class="tracker-day-picker">
    <div class="adjacent-day previous-day"><span>Prev</span></div>
    <div class="day current-day"><span>Current</span></div>
    <div class="adjacent-day next-day"><span>Next</span></div> 
</div>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentDate = moment();

  tracker_picker_update( currentDate );

  $(".previous-day").on("click", function(){
    currentDate = currentDate.subtract(1, "day");
    tracker_picker_update( currentDate );
  });

  $(".next-day").on("click", function(){
    currentDate = currentDate.add(1, "day");
    tracker_picker_update( currentDate );
  });

});


function tracker_picker_update( currentDate ) {
  var tracker_picker = $(".tracker-day-picker");

  // Set current Date
  tracker_picker.find(".current-day span").text( currentDate.format("DD MMM Y") );

  // Set previous Date
  tracker_picker.find(".previous-day span").text( currentDate.subtract(1, "day").format("DD MMM Y") );

  // Set Next Date
  tracker_picker.find(".next-day span").text( currentDate.add(1, "day").format("DD MMM Y") );

  return true;
}
```

For some part it seems to be working correctly, if I like on the `previous-day` element it works properly, the current day is updated with the clicked date and in the `previous-day` element the day previous to the date clicked is updated.

The problem is happening the the `next-day` element.

Here's an example:
http://jsbin.com/yejoful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment object are mutable so when you use [`add`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`subtract`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) you modify the value of the original object.

You can clone moment object before modify its value using [`clone()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/):

> All moments are mutable. If you want a clone of a moment, you can do so implicitly or explicitly.
>
> Calling `moment()` on a moment will clone it.
>
> Additionally, you can call `moment#clone` to clone a moment.

Comment: Wow. One simple change and everything is working fine now. I am now cloning the object when it is passed to the function `currentDate = currentDate.clone();` and everything is working as desired. Thank you for the point out :)